# Can I use angular-material in any commercial project ? Is there any cost for that?

Tags: mit, closed-source

I have using angular material for quite few days. Now I am planning to develop a commercial software using angular material (https://material.angularjs.org/). While going through the license section of the product (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/license) it says -

"The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."

I am not getting the meaning of the above statement. Does it mean that some/all of my source code should have the above license as well (Whereas my product license will definitely be proprietary) ?

As an example, let's say I have one JavaScript file where I am using the angular material components. Is it necessary to add that license there ?
However, the license declaration of the actual angular material components (which are provided by angular material) are intact and not modified.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer; yes, you can. And there is no cost.

MIT is one of the more permissive licenses available. You can use code written using it in projects with other licenses, including other open source licenses and commercial projects.

You merely have to say you used X and that X is licensed under MIT, and made by Y. One advice would be to have this on an about page.

And no, you don't need to include the license in any files which are merely calling the library.

See also [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103273/can-i-use-mit-licence-plugins-in-my-commercial-web-site)